# Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext' despite defining RequestContextListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

My app has multiple spring security configurations and one of them happens to be `Oauth2` (using [this](https://github.com/OKaluzny/spring-boot-security-oauth2-google) eaxmple).

**Spring security in general is getting plugged in via:**

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);             
context.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
context.addFilter(new FilterHolder( new DelegatingFilterProxy( DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME ) ), "/*",EnumSet.allOf( DispatcherType.class ));
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext securityContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
securityContext.setConfigLocation("com.test.auth");
DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(securityContext);
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet), "/");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(createResourceConfig(AuthController.class))), "/auth/*");
```

**Oauth2 which looks like this:**

```
@Order(4)
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration  
public class Oauth2Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {    
        @Bean
        @Order(0)
        public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
            return new RequestContextListener();
        }

        @Autowired
        private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

        @Autowired
        private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

        @Autowired
        private AuthConfig authConfig;

        private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails authorizationCodeResource() {
            AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

            details.setId("google-oauth-client");
            details.setClientId(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.clientId"));
            details.setClientSecret(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.clientSecret"));
            details.setUserAuthorizationUri(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.userAuthorizationUri"));
            details.setAccessTokenUri(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.accessTokenUri"));
            details.setTokenName(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.tokenName"));
            details.setScope(Arrays.asList(authConfig.getPropertyList("oauth2.scope")));

            details.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.query);
            details.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
            return details;
        }     



        @Bean
        public OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter
                    oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter() {
            // Used to obtain access token from authorization server (AS)
            OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(
                    authorizationCodeResource(),
                    oauth2ClientContext);
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter =
                    new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.filterCallbackPath"));
            filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
            // Set a service that validates an OAuth2 access token
            // We can use either Google API's UserInfo or TokenInfo
            // For this, we chose to use UserInfo service
            filter.setTokenServices(googleUserInfoTokenServices());
            return filter;
        }

        @Bean           
        public GoogleUserInfoTokenServices googleUserInfoTokenServices() {
            GoogleUserInfoTokenServices userInfoTokenServices =
                    new GoogleUserInfoTokenServices(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.userInfoUri"), authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.clientId"));
            // TODO Configure bean to use local database to read authorities
            // userInfoTokenServices.setAuthoritiesExtractor(authoritiesExtractor);
            return userInfoTokenServices;
        }

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
            // May need an OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint for non-browser clients
            return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(authConfig.getProperty("oauth2.filterCallbackPath"));
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                    "/", "/static/**", "/webjars/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
                http
                    .antMatcher("/auth/oauth/**")                       
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")                  
                .and()
                    .addFilterAfter(
                        oauth2ClientContextFilter,
                        ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
                    .addFilterBefore(
                        oauth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(),
                        FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
                    .anonymous()                        
                        .disable();
        }

        @Override
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
            return new NoopAuthenticationManager();
        }

}

private static class NoopAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "No authentication should be done with this AuthenticationManager");
    }
}

@Bean           
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

While accessing the callback url `api/auth/oauth/callback`, I get following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope
>   'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton

On searching SO, the suggested solution is to add `RequestContextListener` bean but even after adding that I got no success.

One [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817342/spring-deferred-result-request-scoped-beanoauth2clientcontext-in-the-web-fil) also suggested using `FilterRegistrationBean` but I am not using Springboot so I am not sure whether it would have solved  my problem or not.

**Full exception trace:**

> 2018-02-22 12:47:36,440 - /api/auth/oauth/callback
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext': Scope
>   'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of
>   the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within
>   a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably
>   running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case,
>   use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:355)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.getAccessToken(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
>   you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current
>   request.  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
>     ... 55 more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem. And in this era of `Springboot`, someone who is working on a slightly older system, might find the answer useful, so sharing it.

The `RequestContextListener`needs to be added in jetty configuration like this:

```
context.addEventListener(new RequestContextListener());
```

I was adding it in my security config file, like this:

```
@Bean
@Order(0)
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
    return new RequestContextListener();
}
```

Comment: The scenario described in your question is slightly different. As I mentioned in my answer, this solution is for non-Springboot apps.

Comment: U've saved my day! Tks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can find this useful, add following in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implemntation class:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
}
```